# How to fix 'Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AuthService: (?).'

Tags: node.js, angular

this error occur when application is started.
The terminal is not showing any error but in the browser console.
The last action was i import JwtHelperService from '@auth0/angular-jwt'

The project is in Nodejs, express 4.16.4 and angular 7.2.0
I have included some code 
please help me to find the error
thank you in advance

auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import "rxjs/Rx";
import { JwtHelperService } from "@auth0/angular-jwt";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
import "core-js/es7/reflect";

import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

const jwt = new JwtHelperService();
export class AuthService {
  @Injectable()
  private decodedToken;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  public register(userData: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post("/api/v1/users/register", userData);
  }
  public login(userData: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post("/api/v1/users/auth", userData).map(token => {
      //debugger;
      return this.saveToken(token);
    });
  }

  private saveToken(token): string {
    //debugger;
    this.decodedToken = jwt.decodeToken(token);
    localStorage.setItem("bwm_auth", token.token);
    localStorage.setItem("bwm_meta", JSON.stringify(this.decodedToken));
    return token;
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";

import { LoginComponent } from "./login/login.component";
import { RegisterComponent } from "./register/register.component";

import { AuthService } from "./shared/auth.service";

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "login", component: LoginComponent },
  { path: "register", component: RegisterComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [LoginComponent, RegisterComponent],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    FormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  exports: [],
  providers: [AuthService]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

error on browser

```
compiler.js:2430 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AuthService: (?).
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2430)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.js:18984)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (compiler.js:18877)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableTypeMetadata (compiler.js:19099)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata (compiler.js:19108)
    at compiler.js:19046
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (compiler.js:19006)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:18725)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleSummary (compiler.js:18555)
```

[image of error in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtW8D.jpg)

Comment: `@Injectable()` should be placed **before** the class definition

Comment: thank you this solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

**`@Injectable()`** should be placed before the class definition

```
 @Injectable()
 export class AuthService {

 }
```

Comment: glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You should first add **@Injectable** to your **AuthService**

But this error indicates that the DI cannot resolve the requested parameter asked by the AuthService (HttpClient).

To resolve this issue, you need to include the HttpClient module in your AppModule as this code snippet shows

```
import { NgModule }         from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }    from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    // import HttpClientModule after BrowserModule.
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
     AppComponent,
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

You can see their full documentation here [HttpModule](https://angular.io/guide/http)